# How to describe an equivalence relation given $f:A\to B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There's a lot of online material to determine the partition from the relation, but how do you determine the equivalence relation given a function? Mainly...

> 1. Consider A and B sets and f : A → B a surjective function.
>
> (i) Prove that f determines a partition on A. (For concreteness, you may assume that |B| = n.)
>
> (ii) Describe the equivalence relation determined by this partition.

The question I'm asking pertains to (ii), not (i).

Comment: Well, $x\sim y$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ have the same image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{ f$^{-1}$(b) : b in B } is a partition of A
from the equivalence relation  x ~ y iff f(x) = f(y).